# Can RTMP multiplex messages within a single chunk stream?

Tags: rtmp, live-streaming

Reading the [RTMP specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf), in an effort to write a rudimentary RTMP server, I can't tell whether multiple messages (message stream id) can be sent over the same chunk stream (chunk stream id).

Section 5.3.2 shares two examples: one where multiple messages with the **same stream id** are sent sequentially over multiple chunks for a single chunk stream id and one where a single message is sent over multiple chunks for a single chunk stream id.

But there's no example demonstrating multiple messages with **different stream ids** being sent concurrently over multiple chunks for a single chunk stream id. I can't find anything that would prevent this, but I'd like confirmation.

For example, say you have two messages like in example 2

```
 +-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
 |           | Message Stream ID | Message TYpe ID |  Time  | Length |
 +-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
 | Msg # 1   |         27        |    9 (video)    | 1000   |  307   |
 +-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
 | Msg # 2   |         42        |    9 (video)    | 1000   |  197   |
 +-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Can the RTMP client send the following sequence of chunks?

1. Type 0 message for 27
2. Type 0 message for 42
3. Type 3 message for 27
4. Type 3 message for 27 (completely sent Msg # 1)
5. Type 3 message for 42 (completely sent Msg # 2)

In other words, is chunk 3 expected to use the header from 1 or from 2 (ie. based on message stream id)?

Comment: There is nothing that prevents it, But I don't know of any rtmp servers that support it.

Comment: @szatmary If I were to support it, I'd have to keep a backlog of chunk headers for each stream, right? (That is, in addition to the backlog of chunk headers for each chunk stream.)

Comment: Actually I don't think that's right. For the various chunk types, the spec says _chunks of this type take values from the preceding chunk for the same Chunk Stream ID._ Regardless of message stream id, it would always look at the previous chunk.